# Cómo trasladar al chat los comentarios desde un inicio

Tags: discusión

En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/20802/7242) he puesto en los comentarios el enlace del chat general para no tener que llenar los comentarios de una conversación.

Al trasladar la conversación al chat hemos tenido una larga conversación gracias a la cuál [hemos podido resolver](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/20813/7242) el problema.

Al volver a la pregunta inicial, en los comentarios, me ha aparecido de golpe esto:

[image: comentarios en el chat]

Ese link me lleva a una sala (no sé si temporal) pero sí específica para hablar de *ese* problema que me hubiera ido genial des de un principio.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Hay alguna manera de generar esa sala de chat sin tener antes que hacer una conversación en los comentarios?

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96247/is-it-possible-to-import-comments-into-a-chat-room-without-the-link-appearing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lastimosamente, no.

Según mi experiencia en https://stackoverflow.com, para un usuario cuando aparece esta opción y la usa (lo llamaré @user), lo que sucede es que crea una sala de chat y automáticamente @user entra a la sala de chat. Asimismo, en la publicación se agrega un comentario nuevo con un enlace a la sala de chat, este comentario es publicado por @user (el sistema lo hace, no se preocupen). Esta opción **no va a mover los comentarios anteriores a la sala de chat**, solo es para facilitar la comunicación nueva entre los usuarios y para evitar las discusiones en comentarios.

Para que aparezca esta opción, se necesitan al menos 6 comentarios en la publicación (aún tengo que comprobar si esta cifra es correcta, si alguien pudiese edite esta parte por favor [= ).

Un moderador sí puede mover todos los comentarios existentes en la publicación a una sala de chat, existe una opción para ello. Si creen que es necesario migrar los comentarios a una sala de chat y no ha aparecido dicha opción, entonces pueden reportar la pregunta y colocar un mensaje solicitando que se migren los comentarios al chat explicando por qué debiese hacerse (a menos que hayan alrededor de 10 comentarios o más y ninguno sea ofensivo).

Comment: 2 cosas. 1 - en la pregunta que he enlazado ya me aparece esa opción y sólo hay 6 comentarios (por lo que no son 8, son 6, o al menos en mi caso :) ). 2- es correcto trasladar al chat general como lo hemos hecho ? O es mejor utilizar comentarios hasta que aparezca la opción? Gracias!

Comment: Yo creo que es mejor esperar hasta que aparezca la opción. Sucede que es chat específico para una pregunta/respuesta entonces sería mejor que tenga su propia sala de chat. Al colocarlo en la sala de chat general, habrá mucho ruido por los comentarios de chat de otros usuarios, además si alguien quisiera revisar la conversación porque tuvo un problema similar tendría que darse el trabajo de revisar en qué parte del chat general está y enlazar por sí solo todo lo necesario para esto. Las salas de chat son eternas, aunque al cabo de cierto tiempo de inactividad se bloquea agregar nuevos mensajes.